# Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi im trying to create a WCF but i get this error.

> Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make
>   sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

Error Details

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:3502/Service1.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost:3502/Service1.svc    Metadata inneh†ller en referens som inte kan l”sas. http://localhost:3502/Service1.svc.    Det gick inte att aktivera den beg„rda tj„nsten http://localhost:3502/Service1.svc. Du hittar mer information i serverdiagnostikloggarna.HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost:3502/Service1.svc    Ett fel uppstod n„r http://localhost:3502/Service1.svc h„mtades.    Beg„ran misslyckades med felmeddelandet:--<!DOCTYPE html><html>    <head>        <title>The type 'MinserviceWebb.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.</title>        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />        <style>         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}          p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}         .version {color: gray;}         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }         }         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {          pre { width: 280px; }         }        </style>    </head>    <body bgcolor="white">            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>            <h2> <i>The type 'MinserviceWebb.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.</i> </h2></span>            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.            <br><br>            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'MinserviceWebb.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.<br><br>            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">               <tr>                  <td>                      <code>An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>                  </td>               </tr>            </table>            <br>            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">               <tr>                  <td>                      <code><pre>[InvalidOperationException: The type 'MinserviceWebb.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.]   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +59638   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1434   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598[ServiceActivationException: The service '/Service1.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type 'MinserviceWebb.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found..]   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +495736   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +6   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129</pre></code>                  </td>               </tr>            </table>            <br>            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>            <b>Version Information:</b>ÿMicrosoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929            </font>    </body></html><!-- [InvalidOperationException]: The type 'MinserviceWebb.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.   vid System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)   vid System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)   vid System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)   vid System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)[ServiceActivationException]: The service '/Service1.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type 'MinserviceWebb.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found..   vid System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)   vid System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)   vid System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory.ServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)   vid System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)-->--.
```

config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>


  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share the code you used for the service?

Comment: you have possibly renamed your class from `MinserviceWebb.Service1` to something else without updating the Service1.svc markup page

Comment: What environment are you working in? Is this an IIS server or Development Server?
Have you tried directing your web browser to the same URL?
Finally I assume this IS being hosted on the same machine as you are trying to add the service reference on

Comment: Im just debug the WCF and then i get this problem, i changed Service1.cs to another name but i get the same problem

Comment: @AliRiyadh (I am assuming you are using visual studio) right click on the Service1.svc in solution explorer. Click 'View Markup'. Check that the `Service="Namespace.ClassName"` is consistent with whatever your class is named and that `CodeBehind="codefilename.cs"` is consistent with the filename of the source code

Comment: Post the svc markup please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be your protocol binding.

Only https is turned on and you are trying to get the metadata via http.